# How do I let optional routing parameters allow null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I'm trying to allow null values in one of my controller methods.
It looks like this:

```cs
[Route("items/type/{catalogTypeId}/brand/{catalogBrandId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Items(int? catalogTypeId, int? catalogBrandId, [FromQuery] int pageSize = 6, [FromQuery] int pageIndex = 0)
```

When I try to postman `items/type/1/brand/null?pageSize=6&pageIndex=0` it gives me an error 400

> "The value 'null' is not valid".

How would I go with allowing the null value?

Comment: Make parameter optional `{catalogBrandId?}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make route template parameter optional `{catalogBrandId?}`

```
[Route("items/type/{catalogTypeId}/brand/{catalogBrandId?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Items(int? catalogTypeId, int? catalogBrandId = null, [FromQuery] int pageSize = 6, [FromQuery] int pageIndex = 0)
```

and exclude it from URL

```
items/type/1/brand?pageSize=6&pageIndex=0
```

You should actually use multiple routes to get a cleaner URL

```
[Route("items")]
[Route("items/type/{catalogTypeId}")]
[Route("items/type/{catalogTypeId}/brand/{catalogBrandId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Items(int? catalogTypeId = null, int? catalogBrandId = null, [FromQuery] int pageSize = 6, [FromQuery] int pageIndex = 0)
```

Note the template is no longer optional but the parameter in the Action is optional.

This will allow

```
items?pageSize=6&pageIndex=0
items/type/1?pageSize=6&pageIndex=0
items/type/1/brand/2?pageSize=6&pageIndex=0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try and solve this now. Note though that TypeId is as optional as BrandId but I think I still got your point.

Comment: @PardonMyCheckmate Then add an additional route `[Route("items")]` along with `int? catalogTypeId = null`. You seem to already get the picture